# Getting Deployment triggered by User

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

How can I extract the 'Deployment triggered by' user in a Manual triggered Release pipeline?
(Not the $env:RELEASE_REQUESTEDFOR, the actual deploy triggered by user)

[image]

Comment: Try `RELEASE_DEPLOYMENT_REQUESTEDFOR` or `RELEASE_DEPLOYMENT_REQUESTEDFOREMAIL`.

Comment: Hi friend, is there any update for this issue? If the issue persists, please feel free to let me know:)

Answer (score 1):

> How can I extract the 'Deployment triggered by' user in a Manual
>   triggered Release pipeline? (Not the $env:RELEASE_REQUESTEDFOR, the
>   actual deploy triggered by user)

You can use `RELEASE_DEPLOYMENT_REQUESTEDFOR`, this represents the actual deploy triggered by user you want. And `RELEASE_DEPLOYMENT_REQUESTEDFOREMAIL` is the email of that actual user.

`$env:RELEASE_REQUESTEDFOR` represents the `lance 1` here:

[image]

`$env:RELEASE_DEPLOYMENT_REQUESTEDFOR` represents the real user that trigger the deploy of my `stage1`:

[image]

And these two pics are part of my screenshot in my release-1 page.(pic1 and pic2 comes from the same page).

Hope it helps :)